# C# Thread.Sleep() _ Other time to perform between PCs

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, runtime, sleep

I have a question.

The source below is the thread that moves the panel to the left and right when the button is pressed.

However, it takes about 4 seconds on a test PC if it moved in about 1 second on a development PC.

*Test PCs are better for hardware performance.

I wonder why these results are coming out.

```
 private void move()
    {
        while (Moving)
        {
            SlidePanel.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                if (SlideDirection == 0) // Left
                {
                    SlidePanel.Left -= 4;
                    if (SlidePanel.Left <= SystemSettingbtn.Left)
                    {
                        SlidePanel.Left = SystemSettingbtn.Left;

                        SystemPanel.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            SystemPanel.BringToFront();
                        }));

                        Moving = false;
                    }
                }
                else // Right
                {
                    SlidePanel.Left += 4;
                    if (SlidePanel.Left >= EnvSettingbtn.Left)
                    {
                        SlidePanel.Left = EnvSettingbtn.Left;

                        EnvironmnetPanel.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            EnvironmnetPanel.BringToFront();
                        }));

                        Moving = false;
                    }
                }
            }));

            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
```

- use  [ await Task.With Daly (1) ]
  i have confirmed that both environments have the same running time.
  It feels strange that Thread.sleep(1) is slowing down in a better environment.

Comment: Can you post the declaration of `Moving`?

Comment: @Zer0 I declared the boolean out of the thread. [bool Moving = false] and When a button event occurs change Moving = true - > thread Start

Answer (score 1):

This is not thread-safe.  You need to synchronize `Moving` somehow.  The easiest way is by using `lock`.

There are more efficient ways, but starting here and learning is your safest bet.  Something like this works.

```
private readonly object movingLock = new object();
private bool _moving;
private bool Moving
{
    get { lock (movingLock) return _moving }
    set { lock (movingLock) _moving = value; }
}
```

One important note on why this is required.  `if (_moving)` without synchronization can return an old value.

You can use `volatile` here but, contrary to popular opinion, it still does not guarantee the latest value is read.

---

You will see variance due to `Thread.Sleep(1)`.  It's up to the kernel to handle thread scheduling.  It does not guarantee that time.

---

I also don't understand why you're doing a `BeginInvoke` when you're already on the UI thread.  You can use `Control.InvokeRequired` to check.

What happens if you `BeginInvoke` while already on the UI thread?

It doesn't get executed immediately.  It gets placed in the message queue.  The size of that queue also can add significant variance.

Paint messages have a low priority in the queue.  Why bother painting if there are messages to process that will change the paint?  So this also delays painting.

Comment: Could you provide an authoritative source why volatile would not solve this problem? I have read opinions either way, but have not seen a good source with details of the issues.

Comment: @JonasH What volatile is really meant to do is tell the compiler "don't optimize this", because many compiler optimizations include read write reordering.  Here's one [source](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_The_volatile_keyword) that goes in depth.  I wouldn't call any source "authoritative", including myself.

Comment: the you link provided says that access to a volatile field will emit fences if required on the architecture. And that fences should be sufficient to ensure that the value is up to date. I.e. fences affect both the compiler and the cpu. So I still do not see why volatile would not be sufficient.

Comment: @JonasH No it doesn't. I suggest reading the entire page. Quote: "...documentation states that use of the volatile keyword ensures that the most up-to-date value is present in the field at all times. This is incorrect..." Joe Duffy wrote the example code (he worked at Microsoft, wrote a book on concurrency, and was the lead on the TPL).

Comment: For those that want something easy to use like `volatile` without the pitfalls, simply use [`Thread.VolatileRead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.volatileread?view=net-5.0) (and `VolatileWrite`) instead.